# Given 3 variable possible correlation relations

Tags: probability, correlation, random-variable

Let's say `cor(A,B) > 0` and `cor(B,C)>0`. What can we say about `cor(A,C)`?

So, I am reasoning this way, if A is increasing, B is increasing, since the correlation is `>0`. Same holds between B and C, i.e. when B increases then C increases.

So according to my logic, `cor(A,C)>0`. So what's wrong with my intuition?

An explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: The bounds (which give the limits of the possible values of the correlation) are given [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122888/how-to-infer-correlations-from-correlations/124909#124909). Is that sufficient for your needs?

Comment: I think [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181376/is-correlation-transitive/181380#181380) can answer your question..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that it is not true to say that "if A is increasing, B is increasing, since the correlation is >0". You should say that "if A is increasing, the **probability** of B with greater values is increased, but it is possible for B to decrease".

Anyway, your proof about the relationship between the correlations is not true. It is possible that $cor(A,B)\neq$ 0 and $cor(B,C)\neq 0$ but $cor(A,C)=0$. This can be occurred in the v-structures in Bayesian networks. Consider the following example for the factors affecting the grade of a student in a course:

$\textrm{Student Intelligence} \rightarrow \textrm{Grade} \leftarrow \textrm{Comfortable Exam Environment}$

Obviously, `Intelligence` and `Grade` are positively correlated. The `Comfortable Environment` and `Grade` are also positively correlated. But, `Intelligence` and `Comfortable Environment` are independent (not correlated).

Finally, to find the problem with your intuition note that **"correlation does not imply causation"**. Refer to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation) for more information. 
In the above example, `Grade` is correlated with `Comfortable Environment`, but `Grade` does not cause `Comfortable Environment`. So, it breaks the chain of reasoning mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider a simple example of 2-dim vectors. We can calculate a correlation between them easy.
Let A = (1,0), B = (1, 2), C = (-1,2).
Then cor(A,B) = 1*1 + 0*2 = 1 > 0, cor(B,C) = 1*(-1) + 2*2 = 3 > 0, but cor(A,C) = 1*(-1) + 0*2 = -1 < 0.
So, if we know a sign of cor(A,B) and cor(B,C) we can say anything about a sign of cor(A,C).

Comment: Note that correlation is not simply the dot product.

Comment: The same example can be with correlations.
Let A = (2,4,0), B = (4,3,2), C = (6,3,5). Then cor(A,B) = 0.5, cor(B,C) = 0.327, cor(A,C) = -0.654.