# correlation coefficient bivariate normally distributed

Tags: correlation, bivariate

Suppose that X,Y and X,Z are bivariate normally distributed.
We have

$E(X)=0, Var(X)=10$, 
$E(Y)=0, Var(Y)=6$ and $ρ_{xy}=0.87$

Moreover,

$E(X)=0, Var(X)=10$,
$E(Z)=0, Var(Z)=4$ and $ρ_{xz}=0.87$

Will also Y and Z be bivariate normally distributed ? (I guess yes) If yes, which is their coefficient of correlation?

Posted also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271570/correlation-coefficient-bivariate-normally-distributed

**Added after comment of Whuber**: Indicating as K the joint distribution of Y and Z,i know from the theory of the problem i'm dealing with that K is *for sure* a bivariate normally distributed. I expect this will pose some constraint on the value of $ρ_{yz}$

Comment: The correlation question is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72790, which shows there generally is a range of correlations consistent with this information.  The bivariate normal question is answered (in the negative) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159.

Comment: Comment after some thought on the problem i'm dealing with. Indicating as K the joint distribution of Y and Z, I know from the theory of the problem i'm dealing with that K is *for sure* a bivariate normally distributed. I expect this will pose some constraint on the value of $ρ_{yz}$

Comment: Also see [How to infer correlations from correlations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/122888/805)

Comment: @Glen_b thank you! that's exactly what i needed! 

Taking into account that K (my joint distribution) is for sure a bivariate normally distributed, is there a way to lower the interval of the inferred correlation ?

Comment: The [second part of my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72798/919) demonstrates that restricting the question about the possible range of correlations to bivariate Normal distributions doesn't change anything.  The underlying idea is that for every possible covariance matrix, there is a (multivariate) Normal distribution whose covariance matrix is equal to it.  The simplest proof proceeds from the expression of the characteristic function, which depends only on the mean and covariance.